# (C#) UWP Flag quiz game , passing two variables between pages does not work

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, parameter-passing, uwp-xaml

I want to pass the values of two variables, `correctAnswer` and `totalQuestion`, to the `Done` page when transitioning from the `Playing` page after finishing the game. It should display the number of correct answers out of the total number of questions.

To achieve this, following an online tutorial, I created the `SendData` class within the `Playing` class with these variables and passed them using `Frame.Navigate`. However, it is not working.

When game goes to the `Done` page, it displays default values instead of the correct. Additionally, before adding the conditional statement `'if (data != null)'` in the `Done` file, I had error when clicking the button to return to the main page:

```
System.NullReferenceException: „Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”
```

data was null.

I'm not sure where I made a mistake, and I need this application to work by midnight. Can you help me?

```
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGTi9.png) Playing1
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN2ye.png) Playing2
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GlIR.png) Done
```

I'm sorry for .png files, but the inline code button doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked my reply about handling OnNavigatedTo event?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Frame.Navigate` method to send a data, it doesn't mean you could directly use in the constructor. Please handle the [OnNavigatedTo event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto?view=winrt-22621) of the target page to get the parameter that you send.

Like this:

```
    public sealed partial class TestPage : Page
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       SendData data = e.Parameter as SendData; 

       if (data != null)
       {

       }
    }
}
```